# Can you supress asset messages when tailing the development.log?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, grep, tail

During development of Ruby on Rails applications I have the development log constantly tailing via `tail -f log/development.log`.

I have only started developing in Rails a few weeks ago, so I don't know if the log has always shown this many entries, but I believe assets have just recently been added in 3.1. Regardless, this is an exerpt of my `development.log` for a page call:

```
Started GET "/assets/reset.css?body=1" for 70.63.17.68 at Wed Oct 12 20:10:49 +0000 2011
Served asset /reset.css - 304 Not Modified (1ms)


Started GET "/assets/style.css?body=1" for 70.63.17.68 at Wed Oct 12 20:10:49 +0000 2011
Served asset /style.css - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/application.css?body=1" for 70.63.17.68 at Wed Oct 12 20:10:49 +0000 2011
Started asset /application.css - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 70.63.17.68 at Wed Oct 12 20:10:49 +0000 2011
Served asset /application.js - 200 OK (1ms)
```

There are actually a few more entried, but I think you got the picture of this taking up a lot of space with all the new lines in between each GET request. I also delete all the unused scss and coffee files that Rails creates when using `generate`.

I just want to see all database calls and actual page calls in my `development.log` when I `tail` it.

I was wondering if anyone knows of a way to stop Rails logging these events, or if there is a `| grep` way of excluding everything related to assets.

Help is much appretiated, thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your `config/environments/development.rb` set

`config.assets.debug = false`

Comment: it is obviously it has to help but i still get 
 
      Started GET "/assets/application.js" for 127.0.0.1 at Mon Apr 09     00:16:01 +0300 2012
       Served asset /application.js - 304 Not Modified (200ms)

what can be wrong? (i have restarted server twice)

Comment: When debug mode is off, sprockets concatenates asset files, so you will get log messages only for `application.js` and `application.css`, and not for all files in assets directory.